# webmatrix unable to connect to localhost:port

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost, webmatrix

No idea what's happened here - I've been using Webmatrix to build a wordpress site - everything has been going nicely. Powered off the machine last night, now today am unable to run the site.

Firefox gives me this error -

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:portnumber.
```

I've tried running other sites from Webmatrix, no joy. Uninstalled xampp. Windows firewall is off, Norton firewall has the appropriate exceptions.

Where has localhost gone? Anyone?

EDIT: reinstalled Webmatrix, no change. Reinstalling MySQL atm, will see if that helps.
EDIT: nup. Clean install of Webmatrix, MySQL and wordpress makes no difference.

Comment: Since you've uninstalled xampp, you might have just killed your webserver. I suspect the issue might have to do with Firefox (and / or proxy settings), so try to access your localhost (with and without the port) in another browser as well.

Comment: Something else you can try to see if something is listening on port 80 or port 8080 is opening a `cmd` window and typing `netstat -ano | find "80"` or `netstat -ano | find "8080"`. The last column shows the PID of the process using the port so you can close it in Task Manager (remember to set PID column to display).

Comment: reinstalling xampp at the moment. i've tried hitting local host without the port and from different browsers with no luck. if i can't get it running, will probably just go back to working with xampp and good old dreamweaver...

Comment: there are several iis worker processes running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All seems to be working again - rebooted, swore a little, had a coffee and boom, back in business. I think it was the swearing that helped.

Thanks for the suggestions